# How to handle Apple's automatic app opening while in review

Tags: ios, review

Recently, I think, Apple has added a new internal mechanism, which I guess is meant to reduce the time it takes to review an app. Horray.

This process, automatically opens the app in a lot of different devices.

This causes analytics services (mixpanel, google) to register new (anonymous) users, record relevant events, and in general mess up the data.

How can this be ignored / handled?